# Fetching data with Group by, How to select the latest or greatest id? (PHP to MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to fetch data from MySQL with PHP when a user inputs something. I have this code.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mealplans WHERE plantitle LIKE '%$inputText%' AND `STATUS` = 1 OR plantitle LIKE '%$inputText%' AND userid = '$userid' GROUP BY plantitle, userid";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

It works fine however, it fetches the oldest or first data from the group. How do I select the newest data?

I've search and found possible solutions by using FROM,  JOIN, IN, etc. However, I do not know how to use them since I only know the basics. Hopefully someone could explain one solution for me.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: `ORDER BY` show help you. Something like `ORDER BY rownum DESC` should show the last inserted mealplan first. Or maybe you want `ORDER BY userid DESC`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution that you can do.

You can order your data to `DESC` order. I'm sure that you have an `id`(primary key) in your table.You just have to order all your datas' to DESC order of `id`s .So that your last inserted data set will be the one to be fetched since it's on the top.

change your query to: (add your primary key(in the following query i have added it as `id`) in the `ORDER BY` syntax)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM mealplans WHERE plantitle LIKE '%$inputText%' AND `STATUS` = 1 OR plantitle LIKE '%$inputText%' AND userid = '$userid' GROUP BY plantitle, userid ORDER BY `ID` DESC"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a condition in your query which only retrieves the row having the greatest `id`.
Find out the `id` first and then you can use the same query for that `id`:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM mealplans WHERE plantitle LIKE '%$inputText%' AND `STATUS` = 1 OR plantitle LIKE '%$inputText%' AND userid = '$userid' GROUP BY plantitle, userid
```

After getting the `id` and storing it in a variable (say `$temp`):

```
SELECT * from mealplans where `id` = $temp
```

Comment: Doing MAX(id) will only fetch one row. 
The $inputText is like a search. It should show all meal plantitles LIKE what they inputted. But it will group or merge the same plantitles of the same user. And choose the latest one.